# view MySQL data via modal

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

Hello Community I'm just wondering if someone could help me, i have looked around for my answer abit but i am not quite sure on what i am supposed to do.

I am trying to project my SQL Data into a modal, I can get it all working if i just keep it all in a table but i am trying go for a more aesthetic way about it.

( Edit this is my exact code using DreamWeaver for alot of the php functions )

```
 <?php require_once('../Connections/OnboardingForms.php'); ?>
 <?php
 if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
 function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",      $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
 {
   if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
     $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
   }

   $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

   switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
   }
   return $theValue;
 }
 }

 mysql_select_db($database_OnboardingForms, $OnboardingForms);
 $query_OnboardingForms = "SELECT * FROM Onboarding";
 $OnboardingForms = mysql_query($query_OnboardingForms, $OnboardingForms) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_OnboardingForms = mysql_fetch_assoc($OnboardingForms);
 $totalRows_OnboardingForms = mysql_num_rows($OnboardingForms);
 ?>

 <!doctype  >
```

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">

 <thead>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Company Name</th>
 <th>First Name</th>
 <th>Surname</th>
 <th>View</th>
 </thead>

 <?php do { ?>
 <tbody>

 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['OnboardingID']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['CompanyName']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['FirstName']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['Surname']; ?></td>
 <td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view<?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['OnboardingID']; ?>" id="" type="button" class="btn" </button></td>
 </tr>

 </tbody>
 <?php } while ($row_OnboardingForms = mysql_fetch_assoc($OnboardingForms)); ?>
 </table>
```

```
 <!-- Modal Here -->
 <div id="view<?php echo $$row_OnboardingForms['ID']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

 <div class="modal-content">

 <div class="modal-body">

 <table>
 <tbody>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['OnboardingID']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['CompanyName']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['FirstName']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row_OnboardingForms['Surname']; ?></td>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 </div>

 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this issue or point me in the correct direction.

I am also using DreamWeaver.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Im not sure about this sorry, I am using DreamWeaver due to not know a great deal at the moment i used the Server Behaviors panel that the dmx plugin added.

Comment: Have you tried doing a WHILE instead of a DO...WHILE? One problem that I see is that you are setting $row_RecordSet after you try to use it.

Comment: No I haven't, and I'll post my exact code up I just changed everything in it to make it (I thought I was) easier to read

Comment: I have edited the code to show my exact code including the recordset for said table ( hopefully this makes things abit clearer  )